# hide sender no sms PHP

Tags: php, cell, cellular-network

I would like to develop a web based SMS gateway where sender have option either mobile no. or company nick name can be shown to recipient

For example, nick name ABC can be shown instead of no. 1-212-111-111

Is there anyway to hide sender mobile no and add nick name in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the sender to be your company name, customer support phone number, or anything else. So, This means that your recipients could see “TextMagic,” “Area 51,” “Superman,” or any other name or number you want in the sender field rather than just a phone number. This alphanumeric originator, or sender ID, can contain characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _ (underscore).

Detail [here](http://api.textmagic.com/https-api/sender-id)